# Why does the LM7805 heat up?

Tags: voltage-regulator, thermal, linear-regulator, lm78xx

I'm really not comfortable with things heating up, including this LM7805 integrated circuit wired below.

[image]

Why does this mighty LM7805 heat up?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: also bad, but unrelated here: the LM7805 **needs** decoupling caps. You must not use it without.

Comment: not to mention that cable twisting is not an appropriate way of connecting wire to an IC, or a motor.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought using LM7805 is a straightforward process. Boy I was wrong....

Comment: It is very straightforward! The answer to the question I've referred you to explains what the LM7805 does, in very basic electronics terms. The fact that you need decoupling caps stems from dynamic control theory, in the end; *why* might not be straightforward, but "read the datasheet and see it says you need caps" is pretty straight, I'd say :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I really need to read more...ahahhahahahah!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the assistance, comrade! I think I must weaken the power of 9 V battery and turn it into 6 V so the LM7805 will be usable. Thanks!

Comment: no, you'd simply need to use something else than a linear regulator when you're dropping a non-negligible amount of the supply voltage; 1V difference between in- and output might not be enough for the LM7805 to work properly. Also, using a 5V regulator with a 3V motor was ... questionable, to begin with.

Comment: @Shobeh You can't use a 7805 with a 6 volt input; it won't regulate right. The 7805 needs about 1.5~2 volts of difference between its input and output, if I remember right. If you want to use a lower input to output differential, you'll need a low-dropout regulator (and note that low-dropout regulators are pickier about input and output capacitance, so *read the datasheet*). But really, you should be using a switching regulator if you're concerned about things heating up.

Comment: 9V battery supplying 5V regulator supplying 3V motor.  This seems logical to you!  And you are worrying about the regulator overheating.  I'm surprised the 3V motor is not smoking!  Consider a 3.3V switcher driven by your 9V battery.  SPCLVR - Society for Prevention of Cruelity to Linear Voltage Regulators.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat yeah. The 3 V DC motor could take power from a 5 V, 500 mA charger  and run fast. This baby is hardy!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought the 3 V DC motor could handle the power coming from the 5 V regulator. The motor did work as imagined but the 5 V regulator did seem to be on the verge of burn out....

Comment: I hope the answer I've linked to well explains why that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are feeding the 7805 from a 9 volt battery, so there will be a 4 volt voltage drop over it. If your motor draws 500 mA, it results in power dissipation of:

4 V * 0.5 A = 2 W

In the 7805. Depending on the specific mfg PN the device might have a junction to ambient thermal resistance of 50 C/W. That would result the 7805 heating up

2 W * 50 C/W = 100 C

above the ambient temperature.

Adding a heat sink might drop the thermal resistance for example to 25 C/W, which would result in heating

2 W * 25 C/W = 50 C

You need to measure or check the datasheet to know how much current the motor is drawing and get a heat sink large enough to dissipate it.

Another option is to change to a switching mode regulator. Some of them are pin compatible to 7805 (for example CUI V7805-1500R). They will dissipate substantially less power to heat so your battery will last longer too.

Comment: ouch, 2 watts sounds hot, especially how small the LM7805 is....

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, comrade! I think I must weaken the power of 9 V battery and turn it into 6 V so the LM7805 will be usable. Thanks!

Comment: You can also consider driving it directly from 3 x 1.5  V batteries or 4  x rechargable 1.2 V  batteries. You might end up having problems with the switch lifetime, depending on how you do the power switching.

Answer (score 3):

The DC motor is stalled due to the prop being prevented from rotating hence, the load on the regulator is going to be around 1 ohm (the resistance of a small DC motor that is stalled). That means if the 7805 could produce 5 volts it would also be feeding 5 amps to the load and, we know that isn't happening.

So, the output voltage will be much less than a volt and, the input voltage will be about 9 volts and, the current might be around 100 mA. That means about 1.8 watts of heat produced by the 7805.

Simple answer: circuit abuse.

Comment: I wonder how much power this DC motor eats up. I knew it needs 3 V to make this DC turn but I wonder how much current it needed to complete turn.

Comment: Data sheets and ammeters can give you those answers @Shobeh

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, comrade! I think I must weaken the power of 9 V battery and turn it into 6 V so the LM7805 will be usable. Thanks!

Comment: A 9 volt battery of the type in your picture is barely acceptable for DC motors and, a 6 volt supply to a 7805 is well-below the minimum needed to provide regulation. I urge you to use a more powerful battery arrangement like three AAs in series (4.5 volts) and have them directly connected to your motor.

Comment: If you look closely at the photograph, the motor is not stalled. The blades of the propeller are not in contact with the surface, and the battery isn't connected on one side.

Comment: I wish I could. 3 AAs in series is pretty heavy so I used the single and light 9 V battery and reduce it to 5 V using LM7805 so that the 3 V DC motor can turn. It didn't end well though.

Answer (score 2):

It might have to dissipate too much power or it may be unstable and waste energy into high frequency oscillations as it does not have the required bypass capacitors for stability.

Comment: But why my boy LM7805 has to dissipate that much heat if the LM7805 just eat the power of the 9V battery?

Comment: Any power it has to eat will be converted to heat which will make the temperature rise.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, comrade! I think I must weaken the power of 9 V battery and turn it into 6 V so the LM7805 will be usable. Thanks!

Comment: The recommended minimum input voltage is 7 to 8 volts, depending maybe on exact 7805 model. 6V is too little.